# Liferay 6.2 and google A/B testing not working

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing, liferay-6.2, google-experiments

I'm working on implmentation of A/B testing in liferay using google analytics.
For this, I created pages (original and variants) in liferay. 
Then I created my experiment in google and specified original and variants pages without forgetting to add "?strip=0" to them. 
After running my experiment nothing happen ? 
Can anyone tell me why it didn't work ? Did I forget something ?

Comment: Please elaborate on what the `?strip=0` has to do with A/B testing. It will just (either) make sure that Liferay doesn't minimize your CSS/JS, and deliver them in many uncompressed files, rather than a single compressed one. (or) that the HTML is uncompressed, e.g. contains empty lines and superfluous whitespace... It's been a while since I used `strip`, not sure if it does both or only one of these things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I followed what said in this page https://www.xtivia.com/conducting-ab-testing-using-google-content-experiments-liferay/ and according to the author the ?strip=0 should be added to the urls.

Comment: Given that there's no answer yet: You might want to add all of that information (what did you try, what are your exact steps, what do you observe?) *into the question* rather than "I created an experiment", "it did not work". Describe in detail what you do, what/if you understand why, and what you see. Include your actual steps, not just the link to the blog article you found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve the issue by putting the experiment code in liferay theme instead of the javascript page. Everything works as expected now.